# Template argument deduction in partial specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, specialization

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> class A{
public:
    void test() { cout << "normal" << endl;}

};

//template <typename T> class A<T&>{
//public:
//    void test() { cout << "&" << endl;}

//};

template <typename T> class A<T&&>{
public:
    void test() { cout << "&&" << endl;}

};

int main(){
    A<int&> a;
    a.test();
}
```

The output is `normal` suggesting the ordinary (non-specialised) template was chosen. This may be seem obvious straight away since `int &` is supplied as a template argument and the only available specialisation is one that takes an rvalue reference. But why is it that the second template specialisation cannot be selected by choosing `T = int&` in which case reference collapsing causes `T&&` to become `int&`?

Comment: Template argument deduction only applies to template functions. Nothing is getting deduced here.

Comment: The `T&&` in your partial specialization is not a forwarding reference, that only applies to template argument deduction from a function call. What you have is an rvalue reference to `T`. Reference collapsing does not apply here.

Comment: @Praetorian well, the answer box is a copy/paste away ;)

Comment: @Quentin :) Answers require a bit more diligence, like digging up relevant references.

Comment: @Praetorian Partial specialization matching is rather underspecified, see [CWG 697](http://wg21.link/CWG697).